# Give N the natural order and the order topology. Show that N is not connected. What are the connected subsets of N?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Natural order means $\mathbb{N}$ = {0,1,2,....}, and order topology is generated by the subbasis consisting of positive n negative open rays. Therefore, its basis will be $(-\infty, \infty)$ but I dont know what will be that for $\mathbb{N}$. After this, how do I show that they r separated? How do I show that there exist two non empty open sets U and V, s.t. their union gives the entire space and their intersection will give an empty set?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misrepresent the base of $\Bbb N$. It is generated by the subbase

$$\mathcal{S}:=\{(n,\rightarrow), (\leftarrow,n), n \in \Bbb N\}$$

where, as usual $(n, \rightarrow)=\{m \in \Bbb N: m > n\}$ and $(\leftarrow, n)=\{m \in \Bbb N: m < n\}$

So $\{0\}$ is open as it equals $(\leftarrow, 1)$ and if $n \ge 1$, $\{n\}$ is also open as $$\{n\} = (n-1, \rightarrow) \cap (\leftarrow,n+1)$$

So $\Bbb N$ has the discrete topology as the order topology.

Now any subspace $A$ of a discrete space with $|A|\ge 2$ is disconnected: take $a \in A$ and note that $A= \{a\} \cup (A \setminus \{a\})$ is a disconnection of $A$ in two open disjoint, non-empty sets.

So the only connected subsets are the singletons (such a space is called *totally disconnected*)

Comment: thanks a lot, I got it now. I found out that {n} (i.e. singletons are going to be the connected subsets of N), but I didnt know how to show it well. you did that, appreciate it sir.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun singletons are always connected, in any space, the crux is here (as in your $X = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \Bbb N\}$ in another question) that no larger set than a singleton can be connected.

Comment: can u pls solve that question for me? I think that question has been removed.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun it has been *closed*, not removed. I could still see it. You could edit it (no more screen shot etc.but MathJax) and it could be re-opened, maybe.

Comment: will it be possible if I send u those in personal chat? I hope that will work well. I can send u screenshots of wht I did in your personal chat.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You can show that $\{ n \}$ is open and closed for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by writing $\{n\}$ as the intersection of two ordered rays.

**Edit**: More concretely for $n>1$

$$ \{n\}=\{ x\in \mathbb{N}: \; x< n+1 \} \cap \{ x\in \mathbb{N}: \; x> n-1 \} $$

and

$$ \{ 1 \}=\{ x\in \mathbb{N}: x<2\}. $$

Comment: how to show that {n} is open for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ? If I can show that its open, then that means its complement will be closed which will satisfy the other part that ({n} is closed $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You can write $\{ n \}$ as the intersection of two ordered rays in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is it like  (-\infty,0) union (0,/infty)? Where one a positive open Ray and the other one is a negative open Ray. That’s how I will do for the rest of N?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: I saw dat, its good. but what will be the connected subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ ? I think all the singletons which you showed (i.e. {0},{1},{2} etc are going to be connected subsets of N)